# Finding a hash function, so that the set of hash functions is universal

Tags: hash

Problem:

Let $U = \{0,1,2,3,4,5\}$ be a universe of keys and $T = \{0,1,2\}$ we observe follwing 5 hash functions which map from $U$ to $T$ :

$$h_1(x) = (x+1) \mod{3} \hspace{5mm} h_2(x) = (x+2) \mod{3} \hspace{5mm} h_3(x) = x \mod{2} \\ h_4(0) = h_4(5) = 2 \hspace{5mm} h_4(1) = h_4(2) = 1 \hspace{5mm} h_4(3) = h_4(4) = 0 \\ h_5(0) = h_5(1) =2 \hspace{5mm} h_5(2) = h_5(3) = 1 \hspace{5mm} h_5(4) = h_5(5) = 0 $$

Find a hash function $h_6 : U \to T$ so that the set $\{h_1,h_2,h_3,h_4,h_5,h_6\}$ is a universal set of hash functions.

Questions:

So, I am new with the topic of universal hashing and hash functions. I am although knowledgeable enough to know, that a set of universal hash functions is composed of this following definition.

$$ \frac{|\{h \in \mathcal{H} |h(a) = h(b)\}|}{|\mathcal{H}|} \leq \frac{1}{t}$$

when $t = |T|$

So right now i have the idea that i should choose my hash function so, that:

$$\frac{|\{h \in \mathcal{H} |h(a) = h(b)\}|}{6} \leq \frac{1}{3}$$

Though i do not really understand what the set above means, or how i can manipulate it so that i can essentially get a chance of $\frac{1}{3}$ overall. Essentially choosing that $h_6$ so that my above set is equal to $2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value $|\{h\in \mathcal{H}\mid h(a)=h(b)\}|$ is meant to represent: for arbitrary $a\neq b \in U$, this value is the number of hash functions for which $a$ collides with $b$.

For example, for $a=0,b=1$ we have that $h(0)=h(1)$ only when $h$ is $h_5$ - so this here will be $1$.

But for $a=0,b=3$ we have that $h(0)=h(3)$ when $h$ is either $h_1$ or $h_2$ - thus here, the value will be $2$.

So your task is to find an $h_6$ that will not increase this value for combinations of $a,b$ that already have a lot of collisions.

Comment: Thank you very much ! This really helped me in understanding the problem. I even solved it today !